# Can the shampoos harm the hair or the head skin?

Tags: hair

I heard that if you wash your hair in every day, your hair will fall out.

For example:

This magazine article,
*[Hair loss dos and don'ts for men who are going bald](http://www.news.com.au/lifestyle/beauty/hair-loss-dos-and-donts-for-men-who-are-going-bald/story-fnet0435-1226748810731)*:

> DON'T WASH YOUR HAIR EVERY DAY
>
> Most men don't need to wash their hair every day.
>
> Too much shampoo or conditioner on a daily basis breaks down the natural structure of your hair.

Is it true that shampoos harm the hair or the head skin?

Comment: Can you cite one or more notable sources claiming this?

Comment: @Himarm Your linked info. doesn't help understand this, because it has no references. Also it appears to advertise other products.

Comment: The notability example doesn't need references, and yet often contains advertising, but the prevention.com example CLAIMS THE OPPOSITE - that not washing your hair often enough causes thinning.